# No overload for method 'Open' takes '15' arguments error in official Microsoft code example

Tags: c#

I am trying this code example in Microsoft website, and got that error:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301659
I am using Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition with Windows 8.1
So what could be the problem? Thanks.
updated: I posted a wrong vb example, the link is correct now.

Comment: The link you provided does not contain C# code, nor does it have an `Open` function anywhere.

Comment: I posted a wrong vb example link, just update and correct now.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the number of arguments you provide to the Open method is not correct and that the compiler cannot find a matching method declaration with this number of arguments. 
Which version of Office do you use?
In the sample there is a hint for Office 2003 and Open:

> **Note** Microsoft Office Word 2003 has an additional argument for the
>   Open method of the document. If you are using the Word 2003 PIA,
>   remove the comment notation for the additional parameter for the Open
>   method.

So you need to find the call to Open in your code and adjust the number of parameters (this might also be the reason if you don't use Office 2003). As I understand the call to Open in the sample, the parameters do not provide meaningful information, so you can just remove the comment as stated in the sample or adjust the number of parameters otherwise (remove some, add new "ref oMissing") until a matching method declaration is found; IntelliSense might help you in this when you hover the mouse cursor over the call to Open.

Comment: I am using office 2007.

Comment: I remove the comments and put all parameters in a single line, but same error.

Answer (score 0):

Which error do you get exactly?
Using the COM interface from Office is really depending on which version of word you are targeting.

Following criteria have to be met to make a application work that accesses office components:

- **Use the same target architecture**: That means if your word is installed as a 32-bit application your application also has to be built as a 32-bit executable.
- **Use same version of word**: Make sure that the word version you have installed on your development machine is the same as on the target machines. The interface definitions vary for each version and your application won't work on different versions of word (or any office aplication).

Also all these criteria have to be matched on the target machines. That means when you got 64-bit office installed on your development machine and compile it from there, it will only run on machines that have the exact same version of office installed (same architecture / same version) as you have.

PS: Why are you using Visual Studio 2008 for Windows8.1? There is a newer version available: Visual Studio 2013 Express.
I am not even sure if Visual Studio 2008 has full support for windows 8...

Comment: Because I am developing something for a client who uses windows XP with office 2007.

Comment: @Teemo, is the exact same version of office installed on the other machines (for example all machines have to have Office 2007 32-bit installed)?